# MongoDB - How to rename the specific field from list of unstructured array field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, mongodb-update

I have several documents as given below. Now I need to do rename the ***middlename*** field into ***mid_name*** if ***middlename*** exists in the document.

```
{
    "id":"abc",
    "name":[
      {
          "first_name":"abc",
          "last_name":"def"
      },
      {
          "first_name":"ghi",
          "last_name":"mno",
          "middilename":"xyz"
      }
    ]
}
```

This is something that I expect it to be.

```
{
    "id":"abc",
    "name":[
      {
          "first_name":"abc",
          "last_name":"def"
      },
      {
          "first_name":"ghi",
          "last_name":"mno",
          "mid_name":"xyz"
      }
    ]
}
```

And this is what I have done but it throws the error.

```
db.md_carrierInformation.updateMany({"name.middlename":{$exists:true}}, {$rename:{"name.$.middlename":"name.mid_name"}})
```

ERROR

> MongoServerError: The source field for $rename may not be dynamic: name.$.middlename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work on the update with the aggregation pipeline.

1. `$set` - Set `name` array field.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate each item in `name` array and return new array.

   1.2. `$cond` - Condition for checking current document's `middlename` is not existed.

   1.2.1. If `true`, with merge current document with the document with field `mid_name` via `$mergeObjects`.

   1.2.2. If `false`, remain the existing document.
2. `$unset` - Remove field for `name.middlename`.

```
db.md_carrierInformation.updateMany({
  "name.middlename": {
    $exists: true
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "name": {
        $map: {
          input: "$name",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $ne: [
                  "$$this.middlename",
                  undefined
                ]
              },
              then: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    mid_name: "$$this.middlename"
                  }
                ]
              },
              else: "$$this"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "name.middlename"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZCUgdNCJR3N)